# Xades4j verification - Cannot create a null:null from a http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#

Tags: java, xml, signing, xades4j

Im trying to write program which should verify XML sign using xades4j library.

I have something like this:

```
public static void verify() throws Exception
         {
        FileSystemDirectoryCertStore certStore = new     FileSystemDirectoryCertStore("C:\\(...)");
        KeyStore trustAnchors = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        trustAnchors.load(null);
        CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(trustAnchors, false, certStore.getStore());

        XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
        XadesVerifier v = p.newVerifier();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();     
        String  pathToXmlFile = "C:\\(..)\\TEST20140709_04.xml";

        Document docSource = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(pathToXmlFile));
        docSource.getDocumentElement();

        //Element sigElem = (Element)factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(pathToXmlFile));
        Element sigElem =  docSource.getDocumentElement();
        SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions ssvo = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions();
        ssvo.useBaseUri("http://www.ietf.org/rfc/");

        XAdESVerificationResult r = v.verify(sigElem, ssvo);


System.out.println(r.getSignatureForm());
System.out.println(r.getSignatureAlgorithmUri());
System.out.println(r.getSignedDataObjects().size());
System.out.println(r.getQualifyingProperties().all().size());
    }
```

I receive this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.UnmarshalException: Bad XML signature
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:123)
    at bankconnect2.xades.Signer.verify(Signer.java:392)
    at bankconnect2.BankConnect2.main(BankConnect2.java:591)
 Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.exceptions.XMLSecurityException: **Cannot create a null:null from a http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature element**
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy.guaranteeThatElementInCorrectSpace(ElementProxy.java:249)
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy.<init>(ElementProxy.java:97)
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.SignatureElementProxy.<init>(SignatureElementProxy.java:58)
at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(XMLSignature.java:341)
at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.<init>(XMLSignature.java:326)
at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:120)
```

Size of trustAnchors is 0 - shouldn't be > 0?
Can you point me where I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've noted 2 things:

- `DocumentBuilderFactory` should [be namespace aware](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)).
- You aren't loading anything into the trust anchors keystore. You probably want to [load it from a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream,%20char[])).

If the unmarshalling exception is still present, there's probably an error on the signature XML.

Comment: @Igoncalves

Thank you for your answer.
I've added loading key from file and also set namespace aware to true. Now I have this error:

    org.apache.xml.security.exceptions.XMLSecurityException: Cannot create a urn:ca:std:ccs:pekao:tech:wsdl:ws.001.01:DomesticTransfer from a http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature element

Comment: Without additional info I can't help you. Did you analyse the mentioned element on the XML file? Can you post the XML or upload it somewhere?