# Xades4j Verify signature Xades - EPES: Bad XML signature

Tags: java, xades4j

I am using Xades4J to develop a simple Java program that signs and verifies an XML with XADES-EPES. The sign process seems to be working properly and generates a valid signed XML (although we don't need the SignaturePolicyIdentifier section on it).

*options arguments is from joptsimple library to parse arguments

This is my sign function:

```
void signXML(OptionSet options) {
    KeyingDataProvider kp;
    try {

        SignaturePolicyInfoProvider policyInfoProvider = new SignaturePolicyInfoProvider() {
            public SignaturePolicyBase getSignaturePolicy() {
                return new SignaturePolicyIdentifierProperty(
                        new ObjectIdentifier("oid:/1.2.4.0.9.4.5", IdentifierType.OIDAsURI, "Policy description"),
                        new ByteArrayInputStream("Test policy input stream".getBytes()))
                                .withLocationUrl("http://www.example.com/policy");
            }
        };

        kp = new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider("pkcs12", options.valueOf("certificate").toString(),
                new FirstCertificateSelector(), new DirectPasswordProvider(options.valueOf("password").toString()),
                new DirectPasswordProvider(options.valueOf("password").toString()), false);

        // SignaturePolicyInfoProvider spi = new
        XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesEpesSigningProfile(kp, policyInfoProvider);
        p.withBasicSignatureOptionsProvider(new SignatureOptionsProvider());
        XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();

        // open file
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File(options.valueOf("input").toString()));
        Element elemToSign = doc1.getDocumentElement();

        // sign whole document
        new Enveloped(signer).sign(elemToSign);

        // save output file
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        Result output = new StreamResult(new File(options.valueOf("output").toString()));
        Source input = new DOMSource(doc1);
        transformer.transform(input, output);

    } catch (KeyStoreException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XAdES4jException
            | TransformerException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a sample signature that it creates: (Is it normal to have  at the end of each line of the base64 values?)

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-f5700b65-334e-4905-96f6-ca6156139686">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-f5700b65-334e-4905-96f6-ca6156139686-ref0" URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>h20v8PSCwU5ymBKMj5o8scN3FyMfGCmN8OA2bnRHTnI=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-f5700b65-334e-4905-96f6-ca6156139686-signedprops">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>tEyMfk39qnevJRyLbxQJIGpEBJuCcYRSZNNjm7HfaaA=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-f5700b65-334e-4905-96f6-ca6156139686-sigvalue">
ZhdQPEz7KwYoLTc72rxqUN2rlMfRGmqHd0MVSEeHRf/kmoqAGAqit5tw6k9k8oFCyuPDS/+DoXHJ&#13;
rooMDEMr+cuvbwwDwy77kHT+8JeUuIAamyqP/OByLytxXm/oKHVAraMhHNsGHvhcsYzULHl+n6JB&#13;
fhsYeR6rZdksS+QkgeUYohEktodl20/kyug4ymZjbJ7rCtH6+nRRR1nqc8oVT2ZpgfEaPHqWO06V&#13;
QURYYkuQEPOsNgFUu+YiWAX9pz94tlsOlLu6efBUP4lDZbCSq75J7nVZonmTbj/+mPl/oxpLCAgG&#13;
utWpL1RwyWn454G+Rd/AG3+MLWnbPVVSWUTcNK2gv4S2MVmosGxBnKwA71Zu30S+KaDwoktzZ62X&#13;
ViDLMmf6YbTKhiCIZYdjXPXr9QwSOHr+2B5GNUwo/CoOENJY/sXNHiHXxw+d+cyoowN4faJoVb5C&#13;
YFT7DACHyRd/d6TGdVEviHToTak+xPIK0HGnLvmkqzpICX8SFuMybur5Tttex4hqJNmXI7XbI9pk&#13;
YGLESBvKmzp4O9wLTJdABsLLxZSwU1plagu+5nb8ujIzmngVEHx4yBRprRVr3cBrHKoQBOHAiaGQ&#13;
96qUVTFogIX3vxN/1Q8xKDfB99FlzDdqnc2SW5lgYHnkuHHStJhoaCKRraUWVtU1miT/gMES+YM=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIFgTCCA2mgAwIBAgIJAPzDOBvbJQYvMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMFcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkFVMRMw&#13;
EQYDVQQIDApTb21lLVN0YXRlMSEwHwYDVQQKDBhJbnRlcm5ldCBXaWRnaXRzIFB0eSBMdGQxEDAO&#13;
BgNVBAMMB1Fwcm90ZXgwHhcNMTcxMTI5MDIwMjIyWhcNMTgxMTI5MDIwMjIyWjBXMQswCQYDVQQG&#13;
EwJBVTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkg&#13;
THRkMRAwDgYDVQQDDAdRcHJvdGV4MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAt1+k&#13;
sAGGc1kvhs3AjTfIyBRRBb3sB5C+IlGplS1lOpViUsYOZKT/t0u1PWTxWnTNYpEChSg4ECnbaNje&#13;
nuyIQct5AS+MMMD2R8SSGGfvlhwr/yypEzcIfsOjFMhnV95Kto0abqLDucOyZotZfbaQQcwK7ATI&#13;
/TrumoUX6lRaryeIYBhENRCvmTjcR3ecinL+FSEpEOdXSh0jtHRtoV/HCzHdgNvXXLPD2YkyjY/0&#13;
D9rvHmVmKXtRfnLsiNcc2vMuE0XlfBz/WbP+lOpMKpka5F7ocnDeMJ2Tb24tL60M+DS7IYWOJ4wm&#13;
Vpb9FsBI3mDZ1AndsTIp5lljLIT7CVvgIvIbCxlOx6vcRxjOhpzNLmCJuMuI2dLtg5qn6q4QoLrE&#13;
6LAQZ8Zt9ljK2s33Vc84FZi+nZx6A1enTnLyHjds6BdrzvKLOJeUtLlTbufxNrkQzWSIhI2ZbfhY&#13;
Mn4yC1REj4kH30AKD6YkN028TasJDnv30g9n9eSbZ0fq2buT2DawGAA9GP02daaaOyTmBVJMonpi&#13;
xSD7lN7iR3zvDUxtjIoOi15XZw+2k28VqkwVdOwo3xkz5zVhSxm7Xv1NHdiUO2AUzvWMdBNMTS2t&#13;
0rr31B232UQvuqDHW1ws6em1iA+Lu1X3Z59Mer6Hg2mVclNKSBrYxUSwSv9poZqxXlGH6R0CAwEA&#13;
AaNQME4wHQYDVR0OBBYEFNG3ss8QEfGFgyxHpb54iRRNz9BDMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFNG3ss8QEfGF&#13;
gyxHpb54iRRNz9BDMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggIBACuhTI0prkRc15OI&#13;
HGQq+xhHRfbnG3dUEaXuAYhyDbrRXz2urEjIf2vGPIn7hheOrScSbQgblHq/tV1nQTyRsyHCvZlV&#13;
aE2+OWCfrQDdrwZKE2N2xC1ALgGTtF+I4lXgy6/9OzNVFnV0oZUnO6PN5cH6SVy+RHpO9Lsr5ndI&#13;
YBSuu0Zd7/IsOYY/vWcfJjq3+SnRotgGj0Jf4F7SH74XPz0QkoVKM1z3zGlbF/w8OzJw71yRVkaX&#13;
Ld+TDFC6jDFV+kjQ1k8pa4Hjs2Yko2AmNmpOZmMVjRLTdGLdSU/Gt1ewDp5TsEa2y/5u2PcZY/fd&#13;
dNaMyH7Qx0SmqvYvgG0C3mSGhhFv6++SaXXmo1lQCDgY9OK975KnQPSIHXeuK7oh/82a2ZhmQau0&#13;
B/ISxrjtRJbSHByLefJAkJpRVGowa14Nq/jI/Dvl46LVepTq2eNxbbMmbaW60HMwDS+YfNIwRpRS&#13;
n/W1/7mWLQRRP0Mb1/fjZlIZBV83fynZU5BSsoW+LZ8EWXt+VhtC8SWZ3m3ffk3KKqZDKJTih5c1&#13;
IFz2veIrHZH6O9n3taU+mVuNC8piuG+GBCBPo7dQwFmGo2zZ9BvSqUdytLniuej1PcPBTkcxfhCN&#13;
h5lKWwZCNE5v8RlEd9RbjEC5nAm8kCVvHX5SZivd77Yum8eBMAUQ++M2oNfz
</ds:X509Certificate>
<ds:X509SubjectName>CN=Qprotex,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU</ds:X509SubjectName>
<ds:X509IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Qprotex,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>18213463010308326959</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</ds:X509IssuerSerial>
</ds:X509Data>
<ds:KeyValue>
<ds:RSAKeyValue>
<ds:Modulus>
t1+ksAGGc1kvhs3AjTfIyBRRBb3sB5C+IlGplS1lOpViUsYOZKT/t0u1PWTxWnTNYpEChSg4ECnb&#13;
aNjenuyIQct5AS+MMMD2R8SSGGfvlhwr/yypEzcIfsOjFMhnV95Kto0abqLDucOyZotZfbaQQcwK&#13;
7ATI/TrumoUX6lRaryeIYBhENRCvmTjcR3ecinL+FSEpEOdXSh0jtHRtoV/HCzHdgNvXXLPD2Yky&#13;
jY/0D9rvHmVmKXtRfnLsiNcc2vMuE0XlfBz/WbP+lOpMKpka5F7ocnDeMJ2Tb24tL60M+DS7IYWO&#13;
J4wmVpb9FsBI3mDZ1AndsTIp5lljLIT7CVvgIvIbCxlOx6vcRxjOhpzNLmCJuMuI2dLtg5qn6q4Q&#13;
oLrE6LAQZ8Zt9ljK2s33Vc84FZi+nZx6A1enTnLyHjds6BdrzvKLOJeUtLlTbufxNrkQzWSIhI2Z&#13;
bfhYMn4yC1REj4kH30AKD6YkN028TasJDnv30g9n9eSbZ0fq2buT2DawGAA9GP02daaaOyTmBVJM&#13;
onpixSD7lN7iR3zvDUxtjIoOi15XZw+2k28VqkwVdOwo3xkz5zVhSxm7Xv1NHdiUO2AUzvWMdBNM&#13;
TS2t0rr31B232UQvuqDHW1ws6em1iA+Lu1X3Z59Mer6Hg2mVclNKSBrYxUSwSv9poZqxXlGH6R0=
</ds:Modulus>
<ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
</ds:RSAKeyValue>
</ds:KeyValue>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-f5700b65-334e-4905-96f6-ca6156139686"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-f5700b65-334e-4905-96f6-ca6156139686-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2017-11-30T20:58:18.009-05:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>JkEubWWYvvoh7kOnuAvYeXE4cFamHJ5FOBYt3b3dCj4=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Qprotex,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>18213463010308326959</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignaturePolicyId><xades:SigPolicyId><xades:Identifier Qualifier="OIDAsURI">oid:/1.2.4.0.9.4.5</xades:Identifier><xades:Description>Policy description</xades:Description></xades:SigPolicyId><xades:SigPolicyHash><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>MaW9PDxJruPHhjBVAMWyrF9zP+kMnNqkoQOUXxDDGAk=</ds:DigestValue></xades:SigPolicyHash><xades:SigPolicyQualifiers><xades:SigPolicyQualifier><xades:SPURI>http://www.example.com/policy</xades:SPURI></xades:SigPolicyQualifier></xades:SigPolicyQualifiers></xades:SignaturePolicyId></xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

And this is my verify code that prints Bad XML signature.

```
void verifyXML(OptionSet options) {
    try {
        File file = new File(options.valueOf("certificate").toString());
        FileSystemDirectoryCertStore store = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore(file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(options.valueOf("certificate").toString());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        ks.load(fis, options.valueOf("password").toString().toCharArray());                         
        fis.close();            
        CertificateValidationProvider provider = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false, store.getStore());

        XadesVerifier verifier = new XadesVerificationProfile(provider).newVerifier();

        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File(options.valueOf("input").toString()));

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Element sig = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature").item(0);
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(options.valueOf("output").toString());
            XAdESVerificationResult result = verifier.verify(sig, null);
            out.println("true");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            out.println("false");
        }
        out.close();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

I will appreciate if someone can point me where the issue could be. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
After I checked the stack trace I found the following exception:

```
    xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.UnmarshalException: Bad XML signature
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:130)
    at com.qprotex.Main.verifyXML(Main.java:190)
    at com.qprotex.Main.<init>(Main.java:99)
    at com.qprotex.Main.main(Main.java:81)
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.exceptions.XMLSecurityException: Cannot create a null:null from a http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature element
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685913/xades4j-verification-cannot-create-a-nullnull-from-a-http-www-w3-org-2000-0) that mentions the same error and after enabling factory.setNamespaceAware(true) in the verification method I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.FromXmlSignaturePolicyConverter.getLocationUrl(FromXmlSignaturePolicyConverter.java:71)
at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.FromXmlSignaturePolicyConverter.convertFromObjectTree(FromXmlSignaturePolicyConverter.java:64)
at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.FromXmlSignaturePolicyConverter.convertFromObjectTree(FromXmlSignaturePolicyConverter.java:1)
at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerModule.convertProperties(UnmarshallerModule.java:64)
at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.DefaultQualifyingPropertiesUnmarshaller.unmarshalProperties(DefaultQualifyingPropertiesUnmarshaller.java:83)
at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:175)
at com.qprotex.Main.verifyXML(Main.java:190)
at com.qprotex.Main.<init>(Main.java:99)
at com.qprotex.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

**UPDATE 2**
As I am not using a a SignaturePolicyIdentifier, I did changed my sign function to use XadesBesSigningProfile instead of XadesEpesSigningProfile. The only issue I have now is that it works only if I use KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT")

This works:

```
            KeyStore trustAnchors = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT"); 
            trustAnchors.load(null);

            CertificateValidationProvider provider = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(trustAnchors, false);
```

But this does not work and I get back a "xades4j.providers.CannotBuildCertificationPathException: Trust anchors KeyStore has no trusted certificate entries" exception.

```
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(options.valueOf("certificate").toString());
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            ks.load(fis, options.valueOf("password").toString().toCharArray());                         
            fis.close();
            CertificateValidationProvider provider = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false);
```

Comment: Did you resolve it? I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874419/verification-fails-with-xades4j

Answer (score 2):

- You might have found a bug in the library. I created [an issue on Github](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/135) to track this. Subscribe to that if you want.
- If it really is a bug, it must have been introduced in v1.4.0, so for now, you can try to use v1.3.2.
- Since you say you don't need the `SignaturePolicyIdentifier`, why are you using XAdES-EPES? You could use `XadesBesSigningProfile` instead and produce a XAdES-BES signature.
- Assuming you still need XAdES-EPES, note that you'll need to specify how to obtain signature policy documents for verification using `withPolicyDocumentProvider` on the `XadesVerificationProfile`.
- I'm not sure about the encoded characters after base64 strings, but lets wait to see if this is an issue.

After UPDATE 2:

The exception message seems clear. Your goal is to use the signing certificate as the trust anchor as well? The type of the entry on the keystore needs to be "trust anchor". I guess you should add 2 entries: one with cert/key (type "certificate") and another only with the cert (type "trust anchor"). Or use separate keystores.

Comment: Thanks for your help Igoncalves. I did change my sign function to use XadesBesSigningProfile and now it works but I have a small issue. Please check my update 2. Thanks.